# Python: Test whether a number is within 100 of 1000 or 2000

Tags: python, python-3.x

After reading the problem I had no clue to solve it, so I read the below solution and still dont have any clue what it means. Can anyone walk me through the objective of the problem and how the below code solves the problem?

Below is the sample code to solve the problem:

```
def near_thousand(n):
  return ((abs(1000 - n) <= 100) or (abs(2000 - n) <= 100))
print(near_thousand(1000))
print(near_thousand(900))
print(near_thousand(800))   
print(near_thousand(2200))
```

Comment: do you understand the *math* of the problem?

Comment: I didnt understand the question, so dont know what we have to achieve here.

Comment: The code is trying to check if the number is between 900 and 1100 or between 1900 and 2100, by checking if the absolute value of the difference of 1000/2000 and the number is less than or equal to 100. Elementary math concepts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to TEST if a number is close to 1000 or 2000 (at a distance of 100 maximum). Since it is a test, you want to return True or False: the chosen number IS or IS NOT close enough from 1000 OR 2000.

To sum up you have to build a condition in two parts divided by or:
If n is your chosen number, you will test:

Condition 1:  Is dist(n, 1000) INFERIOR to 100 ?

Condition 2:  Is dist(n, 2000) INFERIOR to 100 ?

dist(a, b) is in this case |a-b|

So in Python, Condition 1 is equivalent to

```
(abs(1000-n) <= 100)
```

and Condition 2 is equivalent to

```
(abs(2000-n) <=100)
```

To be more precise,in Python after defining n, the line (abs(1000-n) <= 100) will return True if it is the case or False if it isn't.

Finally, to get the entire solution you just have to regroup Condition 1 and Condition 2, using the reserved word "or":

Complete condition:

```
(abs(1000-n) <= 100) or (abs(2000-n) <= 100)
```

which will return True if it is the case and false if it isn't.

In the answer you proposed, the teacher stored this condition in a function in order to test it against any wanted number:

```
def near_thousand(n):
    return ((abs(1000 - n) <= 100) or (abs(2000 - n) <= 100))
```

He then execute this function for different values of n:

```
print(near_thousand(1000)) #which will show True
print(near_thousand(900)) #which will show True
print(near_thousand(800)) #which will show True
print(near_thousand(2200)) #which will show False
```

Hoping this helps!